# Who Change The Permissions

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, auditing

Is there a way in SharePoint online to find out what user account changed the permissions on a Document Library folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Unified Audit Log in Office 365](https://docs.microsoft.com/microsoft-365/compliance/search-the-audit-log-in-security-and-compliance) to identify the user.

In the Microsoft Admin center,  you can navigate to https://protection.office.com/unifiedauditlog, add the URL of your site (append it with an asterisk) and you can filter the results.

Answer (score 0):

According to my research, I'm afraid your needs can't be met.

The original site-level audit log has the option of ***Editing users and permissions***, but SharePoint online no longer support choosing specific events to edit. Audit Log Reports will still be available as usual but powered by the Unified Audit Pipeline.

Audit Log in Office 365 doesn't seem to record folder-level permission changes.

[image]

Even if I choose modify the folder, it doesn't display information about permissions

[image]

Comment: "Shared file, folder or site" is the one that worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [View audit log reports](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/view-audit-log-reports-b37c5869-1b47-4a82-a30d-ea20070fe527?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us) works for you.

- Security settings    Reports changes to security settings, such as user/group events, and role and rights events.